# Can I reduce voltage from 3.3V to 1.8V using a 1.5V battery?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, level-shifting

I am interfacing to an EEPROM that works via SPI at 1.8V; unfortunately I do not have a 1.8V power source around and being this a weekend project, I wanted to complete it without going to the shop.

I asked a skilled friend an advice and he suggested I could put a 1.5V AA battery in the circuit to get 1.8V.

Is this a sound configuration? I am a newbie but by gut feelings I feel there is something wrong, in particular regarding current intensity.

[image: suggested example]

**Edit 1:** I know this is a bad idea, but I am asking here to know **why**. I could not find a similar question so I believe it will be useful to have here as a reminder of why not to pursue bad ideas like these. I will accept the answer with the explanation of why not to do this. I know it should be done with a voltage regulator, I am asking if it is possible without it, so answer can be yes/no with an explanation. I am also curious to read about anybody that thinks it is possible.

**Edit 2:** for those interested in the power draw, the EEPROM is a Winbond W25Q64FW and I will use it through a TXB0108 level shifter (side B). For the records, I did not ever try this circuit (in particular after the answers/comments I received) but I am nonetheless very interested in reading what is possible or not.

Comment: I suggest you post the schematic. I foresee other problems like the interface signal voltage levels.

Comment: You could, but the battery is **liable to explode** as you'd be driving a charging current into it.

Comment: Use a level shifter and voltage regulator like everybody else.

Comment: You have little experience with this, OK. Then why come up with your own solutions instead of learning how everyone else with way more experience than you would solve this? Why? It is OK **not** to know about electronics but there is **no** excuse for not learning from others. So as Tom says: use a levelshifter like every sane person would.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie if you read carefully, you will notice that I am asking to validate somebody else's idea, that I have concerns about. This is not even my own solution...I am asking here if this solution is valid, please let's stay on topic.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thanks for the vivid example, that is what I was afraid of :)

Comment: @oldfart added the schematic, however this is not complete. the 1.8V load is for a Winbond W25Q64FW on a TXB0108 shifter side B, so the 1.8V goes on the OE  too

Comment: If its just for powering a eeprom, you can use a voltage devider with 2 resistors.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie why are you attacking him? He asked a skilled friend, he asks here - that is exactly learning from others not coming up with own solutions. After all, this solution is not even his own.

Comment: The flash chip may potentially work, seeing as how little current it draws (except during write/erase). But why risk relatively expensive chips like that? Batteries can also go bad and short out. What then? Will the uC survive if the flash chip begins operating at 3.3V?

Comment: @Džuris I hardly think that anyone who would propose this could correctly be called "skilled".

Comment: @JamieHanrahan according to description he appeared to be more experienced and more skilled than OP. As the offered solution seemed dubious, he re-asked here. OP has behaved exactly like one should do, I don't think he deserved that scolding for "not learning from others" and coming up with "own solutions" as that is the opposite of what the OP does.

Comment: I asked him how to "McGyver" the way out of the problem, and he proposed that solution. I give him some slack for the constrained scenario I described, the only thing I blame him for is that he didn't mention any battery leakage/explosion :)

Comment: I offer a bounty of EUR10 for the first person that can get a consumer AA alkaline cell to explode inside of a month when loaded as first described with the estimated static current draw of the two mentioned ICs.

Comment: @KalleMP - right.  The actual outcome I'd expect is for the battery voltage to slowly deteriorate over several months, until the voltage being delivered to the EEPROM is high enough to destroy that...

Comment: If it's a weekend hacking project, I'd say the answer is a resounding YES YOU CAN, until you can get to the shops on Monday. Although you'd be charging the battery at the same time, EEPROMS don't draw all that much current, so you'd be charing the battery at a low current. I've done it myself although not for EEPROMS. Otherwise, do you have a 1.5V zener diode lying around? **NB:** Also, be sure to disconnect the 3.3V supply before switching it off, otherwise you may be supplying -1.5V to the EEPROM :)

Comment: @DaveBoltman thanks for your comment, that is the type of feedback I was expecting (not to resonate with my question but because I really care to know what would happen in reality)

Comment: If you don't care about battery life too much, you could probably use a resistor divider. (don't forget your decoupling capacitor).

Comment: Sounds to me like your friend is indeed skilled: A skilled troll!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Your friend is telling you how to destroy a battery, potentially violently. Use a proper voltage regulator circuit instead.

---

Batteries are not designed to be used a voltage regulators. While it is true that in an ideal world your proposed circuit would work (after all, an ideal battery drops its rated voltage at any current), in practice things are a little different.

All the current drawn from the 1.8V supply will have to flow from the 3.3V supply, into the battery + terminal, then out of the battery - terminal. This is in effect driving a charging current into the battery. The battery is acting as a load.

There is a reason that the batteries have a warning "Do No Recharge" printed on them, charging them can cause venting, in a potentially violent manner. Certainly a messy one.

---

Now you will be wondering, but what if I were to use a rechargeable battery. Initially, it would probably work ok. However the output voltage will drop as the battery charges up.

The voltage across the battery will keep increasing until either the full 3.3V is dropped across it, or the battery is damaged by over-voltage charging.

In any case this will not give you a stable output voltage, as the cell voltage will vary with the current drawn by the load. It is really little different to using a resistor as a regulator, which doesn't work well.

---

The proper solution is to use a voltage regulator circuit. There are many designs. Shunt regulators using Zener diodes, Linear Regulator ICs (e.g. LM317), Transistor series voltage regulators.

Comment: I have to write to this EEPROM a few times, so total active time would be minutes when I am finished with this circuit. But regardless, I understand your explanation applies as well. I am going to pick this answer if nothing better is posted. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Many varieties of rechargable batteries will also fail violently and messily when overcharged.

Comment: @gdm85 sometimes minutes is long enough to male battery go boom. If you really, really want to do it, do it on a wide abandoned concrete area, with you on the other side of a wall than battery and *assume* it will explode. This will give you a better *chance* to avoid damage. But hey, you will save US $0.67 - the cost of LM317 based circuit from AliExpress.

Comment: @zwol Some (NiMH) batteries may be charged indefinitely(TM) at 1/10C or less (trickle charge).

Comment: The AA cell would likely last a week of driving a small circuit in forward of reverse mode (see fix in other answer) and consumer alkaline batteries are also rechargeable "within limits" and this would likely be no more than a trickle charge in any event that would keep the battery full until no longer needed in this project.  Do not leave connected unattended and you will be fine.

Comment: @Molot - or $0.02 - the cost of a pair of 1N4001s (assuming 2.1v is within the max voltage range for the EEPROM).

Comment: @Jules: Wouldn't two 1N4001's drop the result to 1.9V?

Comment: @caf - at low current, the drop is 0.6v.  It doesn't reach 0.7v until about 200mA, which is likely to be somewhat more than an EEPROM would use.

Answer (score 35):

Let me show you exactly why this is a bad idea to use a battery in this manner. The following simulation shows an example with a 100mA load. As you can see this forces 100mA of current to flow in the battery as well.

[image]

If you use an alkaline battery this will be causing a charging action which cause an eventual heating of the battery and it may explode or at a minimum burst a seal and leak.

If you tried a rechargeable battery technology such as a lithium type it will soon become over charged and these are likely to even catch fire when over charged too much.

**There is a safe way to use a battery to regulate the output voltage** in a circuit like this. If you can evaluate your load current requirements carefully then you can place a ballast resistor across the battery as shown below. You must size the ballast resistor so that the battery current is always discharging the battery when the load current goes from zero to whatever maximum current that your load requires. I have shown values suitable for loads up to 50mA.

[image]

In this way the battery operates as a shunt regulator. The ballast resistor is wasteful of the battery energy but it does achieve the OP's goal of how to get 1.8V for a quick one time application.

Comment: Use of a rechargeable battery, and including some series diodes in the shunt path, will make the shunt responsive to the  state-of-charge of the battery, avoiding overdischarge by letting it charge when low, and avoiding overcharge by shunting more when full.  The voltage will still vary somewhat, but less.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, and the effort you put into visualizations. I can only pick one answer unfortunately..but I think this is equally good and completes the one I chose

Comment: +1 for the shunt resistor that makes it perfectly useable.  Problem still remains when 3V3 supply is at 0V and the rail goes negative if not disconnected with a real switch.

Comment: If you're going to add the shunt resistor, you might as well go the next step and remove the battery to leave a voltage divider...

Comment: @TripeHound: A battery serves to stabilize the voltage in the divider.  It won't be perfectly constant, but it will be much more consistent.

Answer (score 4):

It looks, on paper, like it would would, but...

The output voltage of this arrangement may be a bit less than you might expect. The battery may output 1.5V under a nominal load, but to drive a current back into it may require a small additional potential, which in your circuit, would come at the expense of output voltage.

Regardless, what makes this a **bad (potentially dangerous)** idea is that when you run a charging current into a single use battery, you force chemical reactions to occur inside the battery for which it was never designed. A likely reaction will be the formation of heat and explosive gases which the cell cannot dispose of. This can lead to a build-up of pressure until the cell ruptures (explodes), releasing potentially harmful, corrosive, and/or flammable chemicals.

Even using a rechargeable battery in this way is a bad idea, because the voltage across its terminals will vary according to its charge state, giving you a not-very-predictable output voltage, and again, you risk overcharging it with the potential of similar consequences; overcharging typically causes (again) chemical reactions to occur for which the battery was not designed. Rechargeables only charge safely in a circuit designed with that purpose in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your friend was not suggesting this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ295h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A 1.5V alkaline battery is closer to 1.65 when fully charged and not under a high load. And that may be close enough to 1.8V to work for your needs. Consult the spec sheet. Or if this is an inconsequential hobby project, maybe you just build it and see if it works.

Or perhaps the suggestion was:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBChtS.png)</sup>

Either of these approaches will work. Unlike the arrangement you have drawn, they do not rely on running the battery "backwards" to charge it.

Comment: I'm a total electronics noob so I'm probably missing the point but... You seem to be saying that (under certain circumstances) a 1.5V battery is really 1.65V, which is close enough to 1.8V that it'll probably work. Given that the goal is to jury-rig a 1.8V supply, what are the 3.3V sections of your circuits for? Why not just use the battery on its own?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm assuming whatever is interfacing to this EEPROM, whatever has been built so far, still needs a 3.3V supply.

Comment: I reported his drawing 1:1; but thanks for these circuits, I find them interesting. The EEPROM is a Winbond W25Q64FW on a TXB0108 shifter side B, so yeah, really low power draw.

Answer (score 2):

if it's low current, and your 3v3 has sufficient drive, just use a resistive divider- let's say 83r to + and 100r to gnd. The center point will give you 1v8. Yes, that will droop as you draw current and long term it's nasty. But it'll work for the few cycles you need.
The reisitor values could be scaled to match what you have hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

As described by other answers, the most important thing you have to understand is that you are unintentionally charging this battery. Assuming the battery is not designed to be charged, you are expecting some flames upon prolong usage.

Instead of this method, there are many methods that utilise "Voltage Regulators". Take a look at LM334 instead. With proper resistor biasing, you can get perfect 1.8V output.

Remember, EEPROMs might misbehave if the power source is not stable. You might be wreaking your head on things for your simple mistake of not choosing a proper power source.

Answer (score 1):

Independent of the battery problem:

If you have a selection of silicon diodes and/or LEDs, these can be used to achieve the kind of voltage drop you need. You might want some resistor parallel to the IC to get the diode forward voltage into a stable section of the curve.

Mind that most ICs absolutely cannot stand being driven with input voltages that exceed their supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a weekend hacking project, I'd say the answer is a resounding **YES YOU CAN**, until you can get to the shops on Monday.

Although you'd be charging the battery at the same time, EEPROMS don't draw all that much current, so you'd be charging the battery at a low current. I've done it myself although not for EEPROMS. Otherwise, do you have a 1.5V zener diode lying around?

**NB:** Also, be sure to disconnect the 3.3V supply before switching it off, otherwise you may be supplying -1.5V to the EEPROM :)